# How can I check which version of mup I'm using in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

How can check which mup version we are used in meteor? 
I am using meteor 1.2.1 version.
mup command is showing below result but there is no command to check mup version.

### Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments

### Valid Actions

init          - Initialize a Meteor Up project
setup         - Setup the server

deploy        - Deploy app to server
reconfig      - Reconfigure the server and restart

logs [-f -n]  - Access logs

start         - Start your app instances
stop          - Stop your app instances
restart       - Restart your app instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `which mup` to find out which mup you are using. Then follow the symbolic link to see where is installed, and check the content of the `package.json` file

e.g.

```
➜  ~ which mup
/home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/bin/mup
➜  ~ ls -la /home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/bin/mup
lrwxrwxrwx 1 oliver oliver 32 Jun 29 10:49 /home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/bin/mup -> ../lib/node_modules/mup/index.js
➜  ~ ls -l /home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/lib/mup 
ls: cannot access '/home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/lib/mup': No such file or directory
➜  ~ ls -l /home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/lib/node_modules/mup 
total 56
-rw-r--r--   1 oliver oliver  5659 Jun 14 17:19 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 oliver oliver  3135 Jun 14 13:21 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x   8 oliver oliver  4096 Jun 29 10:49 docs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 oliver oliver    65 Mar 11 02:16 index.js
drwxr-xr-x   4 oliver oliver  4096 Jun 29 10:49 lib
drwxr-xr-x 171 oliver oliver  4096 Jun 29 10:49 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 oliver oliver  3972 Jun 29 10:49 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 oliver oliver 24283 Jun 14 13:21 README.md
➜  ~ grep _id  /home/oliver/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.0/lib/node_modules/mup/package.json
  "_id": "mup@1.2.11",
➜  ~
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver,I think this is the Mac command, But i am using Window so which command i used for this.

Comment: You can use the `where` command, and follow the same logic (follow the shortcuts)